# F#: Nested discriminated unions and matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I have 2 nested discriminated unions:

```
type ServiceTypes =
    | Contexts
    | Context of int
    | Producers

type ServiceActions =
    | Get of ServiceTypes
    | Update of ServiceTypes
```

And a nested match statement:

```
let s_action = match action with
               | Get(stype) -> sprintf "Get%s" (match stype with
                                                | Contexts -> sprintf "Contexts"
                                                | Context(id)  -> (sprintf "Context/%d" id))
                                                | _ -> raise (RequestException("get"))
               | Update(stype) -> sprintf "Update%s" (match stype with
                                                      | Producers -> (sprintf "Producers")
                                                      | _ -> raise (RequestException("update")))
```

The goal is to build a request string with a call looking like that `req.Send(Update Producers)`.

Anyway for a reason that I do not understand, the compiler gives me 2 warnings:

1. on the `Update(stype)` I get a **This rule will never be matched**
2. on the the first `match stype` I get a **Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value 'Producers' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).**

So the question is why do I get these 2 warnings? Did I miss something on the way matching works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your closing parenthesis is in the wrong place.

```
| Context(id)  -> (sprintf "Context/%d" id))
| _ -> raise (RequestException("get"))
```

should be

```
| Context(id)  -> (sprintf "Context/%d" id)
| _ -> raise (RequestException("get")))
```

---

Indeed, for the sake of clarity I would get rid of *all* extraneous parentheses (which in this case is actually every parenthesis):

```
let s_action =
    match action with
    | Get stype    -> match stype with
                        | Contexts   -> "Contexts"
                        | Context id -> sprintf "Context/%d" id
                        | _          -> RequestException "get" |> raise
                      |> sprintf "Get%s"
    | Update stype -> match stype with
                        | Producers -> "Producers"
                        | _         -> RequestException "update" |> raise
                      |> sprintf "Update%s"
```

Personally I find this more readable, but of course that's subjective so YMMV.

Comment: Arf... I thought I didn't understand the pattern matching :P At least it was just a stupid syntax mistake. Great demo on how to get rid of the extra parentheses I like it a lot (I updated my code). Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 17):

While nested match expressions are sometimes warranted, in this particular case I would write a more readable single-level match, if I were you:

```
let s_action = 
   match action with
   | Get Contexts     -> "GetContexts"
   | Get (Context id) -> sprintf "GetContext/%d" id
   | Update Producers -> "UpdateProducers"
   | Get _    -> raise (RequestException "get")
   | Update _ -> raise (RequestException "update")
```

which achieves exactly the same effect as your code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you closed the paratheses in the wrong point, your code actually becomes:

```
let s_action =
  match action with
  | Get(stype) -> sprintf "Get%s" (match stype with
                                   | Contexts -> sprintf "Contexts"
                                   | Context(id)  -> (sprintf "Context/%d" id))
  | _ -> raise (RequestException("get")) (* Closing parenthesis should be here *)
  | Update(stype) -> sprintf "Update%s" (match stype with
                                         | Producers -> (sprintf "Producers")
                                         | _ -> raise (RequestException("update")))
```

Obviously you can see the first `match stype with` doesn't cover `Producers` and the last pattern `Update(stype)` never matches due to the previous pattern of `_`. Therefore, all compiler warnings are justified.

You seem to overuse paratheses; here is a cleaned up version:

```
let s_action =
 match action with
 | Get stype -> sprintf "Get%s" <| match stype with
                                   | Contexts -> sprintf "Contexts"
                                   | Context id -> sprintf "Context/%d" id
                                   | _ -> raise <| RequestException "get"
 | Update stype -> sprintf "Update%s" <| match stype with
                                         | Producers -> sprintf "Producers"
                                         | _ -> raise <| RequestException "update"
```